# Gpupdate does not update changed registry values

Tags: windows

Last year I implemented a piece of SW which changes the power button action according to a SW state. The SW does it by changing the registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\7648EFA3-DD9C-4E3E-B566-50F929386280\ACSettingIndex
```

and execute gpupdate.exe. This worked just fine then. But a year later I received a bug report claiming that it does not work anymore. My piece of SW however still works the same way (changes registry values and updates gpupdate). I tried to recreate the problem by manually changing the registry values and calling gpudate, but I get the same result. Calling gpresult Show, that the value is not the same as I set in the registry. However when i change the registry value and restart the Computer, the changed value is applied.

Output of gpresult:

```
C:\windows\system32>gpresult /R /V

Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0 c 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Created on 8/12/2015 at 7:33:22 AM


RSOP data for Domain\User on ComputerName : Logging Mode
---------------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Standalone Workstation
OS Version:                  6.3.9600
Site Name:                   N/A
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               Profile
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------

Last time Group Policy was applied: 8/12/2015 at 7:27:25 AM
Group Policy was applied from:      N/A
Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
Domain Name:                        Domain Name
Domain Type:                        <Local Computer>

Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Local Group Policy

The computer is a part of the following security groups
-------------------------------------------------------
    System Mandatory Level
    Everyone
    SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$TIGNUPPA
    BUILTIN\Users
    NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE
    CONSOLE LOGON
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    BDESVC
    BITS
    CertPropSvc
    DsmSvc
    Eaphost
    hkmsvc
    IKEEXT
    iphlpsvc
    LanmanServer
    lfsvc
    MMCSS
    MSiSCSI
    MsKeyboardFilter
    NcaSvc
    RasAuto
    RasMan
    RemoteAccess
    Schedule
    SCPolicySvc
    SENS
    SessionEnv
    SharedAccess
    ShellHWDetection
    wercplsupport
    Winmgmt
    wlidsvc
    wuauserv
    LOCAL
    BUILTIN\Administrators

Resultant Set Of Policies for Computer
---------------------------------------

    Software Installations
    ----------------------
        N/A

    Startup Scripts
    ---------------
        N/A

    Shutdown Scripts
    ----------------
        N/A

    Account Policies
    ----------------
        N/A

    Audit Policy
    ------------
        N/A

    User Rights
    -----------
        N/A

    Security Options
    ----------------
        N/A

        N/A

    Event Log Settings
    ------------------
        N/A

    Restricted Groups
    -----------------
        N/A

    System Services
    ---------------
        N/A

    Registry Settings
    -----------------
        N/A

    File System Settings
    --------------------
        N/A

    Public Key Policies
    -------------------
        N/A

    Administrative Templates
    ------------------------
        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVDisableBDE
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVAllowBDE
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\FVE\RDVConfigureBDE
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id:    Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\7648EFA3-DD9C-4E3E-B566-50F929386280\ACSettingIndex
            Value:       3, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization\LockScreenImage
            Value:       67, 0, 58, 0, 92, 0, 85, 0, 115, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 92, 0, 72, 0, 65, 0, 77, 0, 73, 0, 76, 0, 84, 0, 79, 0, 78, 0, 45, 0, 66, 0, 97, 0, 99, 0, 107, 0, 103, 0, 114, 0, 111, 0, 117, 0, 110, 0, 100, 0, 92, 0, 72, 0, 97, 0, 109, 0, 105, 0, 108, 0, 116, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 45, 0, 69, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 97, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 45, 0, 49, 0, 50, 0, 56, 0, 48, 0, 120, 0, 56, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 46, 0, 106, 0, 112, 0, 103, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled


USER SETTINGS
--------------

Last time Group Policy was applied: 8/12/2015 at 7:22:00 AM
Group Policy was applied from:      N/A
Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
Domain Name:                        INSTINCT-T404
Domain Type:                        <Local Computer>

Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Local Group Policy

The user is a part of the following security groups
---------------------------------------------------
    None
    Everyone
    Local account and member of Administrators group
    HomeUsers
    BUILTIN\Administrators
    BUILTIN\Users
    REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON
    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    Local account
    LOCAL
    NTLM Authentication
    High Mandatory Level

The user has the following security privileges
----------------------------------------------

    Bypass traverse checking
    Manage auditing and security log
    Back up files and directories
    Restore files and directories
    Change the system time
    Shut down the system
    Force shutdown from a remote system
    Take ownership of files or other objects
    Debug programs
    Modify firmware environment values
    Profile system performance
    Profile single process
    Increase scheduling priority
    Load and unload device drivers
    Create a pagefile
    Adjust memory quotas for a process
    Remove computer from docking station
    Perform volume maintenance tasks
    Impersonate a client after authentication
    Create global objects
    Change the time zone
    Create symbolic links
    Increase a process working set

Resultant Set Of Policies for User
-----------------------------------

    Software Installations
    ----------------------
        N/A

    Logon Scripts
    -------------
        N/A

    Logoff Scripts
    --------------
        N/A

    Public Key Policies
    -------------------
        N/A

    Administrative Templates
    ------------------------
        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowCpl
            Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\GroupPolicyRefreshTime
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoClose
            Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System\GroupPolicyRefreshTimeOffset
            Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

        GPO: Local Group Policy
            Folder Id: Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowCpl\1
            Value:       66, 0, 105, 0, 116, 0, 76, 0, 111, 0, 99, 0, 107, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 68, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 118, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 69, 0, 110, 0, 99, 0, 114, 0, 121, 0, 112, 0, 116, 0, 105, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0
            State:       Enabled

    Folder Redirection
    ------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Browser User Interface
    ----------------------------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Connection
    ----------------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer URLs
    ----------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Security
    --------------------------
        N/A

    Internet Explorer Programs
    --------------------------
        N/A

C:\windows\system32>
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Best Regards
Fabio